# Native DLL Resolve for P/Invoke and User Expectations

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

I've written a .NET assembly which uses P/Invoke to expose functionality of a native 3rd party library. I am, however, not distributing this library with my assembly. This means that the responsibility is on the user to provide the library through whatever means required. Which leads me to my question:

As either a library author with experience in this situation or a potential user of this assembly, what are some common user expectations one would have for resolving the DLL location in this use case?

- Is the default Windows DLL search order enough? "If it blows up, it blows up. They should have read the documentation."
- Should I automatically expand `%PATH%` at run-time to common library install locations to try and find it or at least increase the chances? I'm not really a fan of this as we're changing state behind the scenes.
- Should I provide some form of configuration setting to allow the user to specify the location and then manually call `LoadLibrary`?

Comment: what users are we talking about ? developers ? endusers ?

Comment: Users would be other developers, yes.

Comment: please see my answer below...

Answer (score 0):

As per comments the users are developers:

I would go with convention over configuration... basically default Windows DLL search order... plus a configuration setting for situations where configuration is needed... if that setting is configured it takes precedence...